# Where is Castle Windsor FromAssembly class located?

Tags: castle-windsor

As you can see in [Windsor wiki](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx#codeFromAssemblycode_class_7)

There is a class named FromAssembly to help me with installers. But i'm unable to find it anywhere in Castle.*
I'm using .NET 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source code and do a crtrl-f on the solution:

http://github.com/castleproject/Castle.InversionOfControl

You will need a git client tool, Follow the instructions on the [TortoiseGIT](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) site to get one up and running if you dont have one already.

Comment: Does that mean, that this class is only availiable in trunk?

Comment: Thats true, this class is only in master branch, not the released one

Comment: The wiki covers upcoming version 2.5 and the class is one of the new additions there.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I just ran into the same problem. Took a little while to find FromAssembly (I should get ReSharper). Finally found it!

```
using Castle.Windsor.Installer;
```